# Passing variable from $_.SamAccountName to piped command

Tags: powershell

Could anyone tell me how to get the username, Identity Reference and Access Control Type listed like the example below?

```
Username         IdentityRefrerance        AccessControlType
fred             BuiltIn\Account Operator  Allow
```

I have created the below PS script but i cant get the username passed over.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Set-Location AD:
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | % {$_.SamAccountName}

foreach ($User in $Users) {
    (Get-Acl (Get-ADUser -Identity $User).DistinguishedName).Access | 
    Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Account Operators"} return true |
    select IdentityReference, AccessControlType
}
```

Comment: % is a shortcut for `foreach`. Use `$Users=Get-ADUser -Filter * | select DistinguishedName, SamAccountName}` instead of `$Users=Get-ADUser -Filter * | % {$_.SamAccountName}` as you will reference to the DN later. You need a reference object to query the ACL for. You cant list all access rights to simply * (everything).  Also you dont need to `set-Location AD:` if you are not working with get-childitem etc. cmdlets.

Comment: @Martin He wants to check ACLs of AD objects, so he most definitely does need to change the location to the `AD:` drive.

Comment: It will also work without it, if you specify `-path` with drive: `get-acl -path "AD:\$($user.DistinguishedName)" | select -ExpandProperty access |ft`

Comment: @Martin Yes. But he doesn't do that in his code, and either way the drive *is* required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to loop twice or call `Get-ADUser` multiple times. Just run `Get-Acl` on the objects returned by the first `Get-ADUser` and add the username with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | ForEach-Object {
  $username = $_.SamAccountName
  (Get-Acl $_.DistinguishedName).Access | 
    Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Account Operators"} |
    Select-Object @{n='Username';e={$username}}, IdentityReference,
                  AccessControlType
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar it worked a treat is there away of returning true if it equals a match.?

Comment: @delboy82 That depends. What is the purpose of returning "true"? Return where? For each match or once if you get any match?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a bit tricky at first glance.  But the answer is actually pretty easy!

You want the property of SamAccountName, which we already have from running the `Get-ADUser` command.  Since we're stepping through each of those results using `ForEach($user in $users)`, you can reference that property at any time by using `$user.SamAccountName`.

I think this captures what you're trying to do:

```
foreach ($User in $Users) {
    (Get-ACL (Get-ADUser -Identity $User).distinguishedname).access | 
    where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq "BUILTIN\Account Operators"} return true |
    select $user.SamAccountName, identityreference, accesscontroltype
}
```